# What is difference between pallet-babe and sp-consensus-babe?

Tags: consensus, babe

Here is `sp_consensus_babe`  https://releases.parity.io/substrate-rustdoc/src/sp_consensus_babe/lib.rs.html#86
and `pallet_babe` :https://crates.parity.io/src/pallet_babe/lib.rs.html#18-975

What is difference between them and when to use each of them?

Answer (score 2):

The first part of `sp-consensus-babe` **sp** stands for *substrate primitives*, meaning packages that usually includes elements providing the foundational structures and functionalities.

In this case, `sp-consensus-babe` is a crate that is used by the [BABE pallet](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/401f8a3e9448db854f5605b679fa085b8f445039/substrate/frame/babe/Cargo.toml#L26-L27).

You might use BABE pallet when you want to include such a pallet in your runtime (blockchain) because you want your blockchain to produce blocks following the [BABE](https://wiki.polkadot.network/docs/learn-consensus#block-production-babe) block production mechanism.

You might use primitives from `sp-consensus-babe` in a context where you are building a crate or some code, and you might need the primitives existing there. Just including it in the `Cargo.toml` file, as [others](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/401f8a3e9448db854f5605b679fa085b8f445039/cumulus/client/relay-chain-minimal-node/Cargo.toml#L30-L31) do, should be enough.